# Python Dataframe always select middle row

Tags: python, dataframe

My output dataframe will have sometimes 1 or 5 or 10 rows. How do I select exactly the middle row.

My code:

```
df =
    val
0    10   
1    20
2    30
3    40

mid_rw = round(len(df)/2)

print(df.iloc[mid_rw])
```

But above does not work if there is one row only? How to make it work for one row as well?

Comment: Please clarify your goal, as the code you posted doesn't get the "middle" row, as there is no "middle" row in a series with 4 rows. Do you mean the middle row, rounded down? Also, on a on-element series, this correctly returns the only row, so it would help to clarify that statement as well. Can you add more examples and the expected vs actual outcomes for each?

Answer (score 1):

how about this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'val':[10,20,30,40]})
mid_rw = int(len(df)/2)
print(df.iloc[mid_rw])
```

`int` will round to floor